# Kronecker product of matrices

Tags: lapack, blas, scalapack

I have to use Kronecker product of a matrix with a unit matrix is there any routine in ScaLapack or Lapack which can do so efficiently.

Comment: Can you write out in formulas what you want to do? It would also help if you explained *why* you want to do that and what you want to do with the result, since there may be more efficient ways of doing that without building the Kronecker product.

Comment: Kronecker product is basically a space allocation problem with some additional overhead of scalar multiplesof the matrix. Hence any efficient allocation would be an efficient implementation.